# Power switch: leaving battery connected at one terminal

Tags: batteries

Just wondering if there is any real-world practical difference between a power switch that disconnects *both* terminals of a battery vs a switch that just disconnects one terminal.

Are there any possible consequences for leaving the negative terminal of a battery always connected to earth, it terms of battery lifetime or self discharge?

Will a battery that's fully disconnected at both terminals maintain its charge for longer?

Which approach is taken in real world consumer devices?

Comment: An important aspect CAN BE safety. If only one lead is disconnected there may be other paths which MIGHT be made, dependent very much on what the overall circuit looks like.

Answer (score 2):

If your single switch truly completely disconnects one battery terminal, then there is no difference in self-discharge of the battery.

However, this is one of these cases where there might be a difference between ideal circuit theory, and messy reality. In messy reality, there might be other conductors appear across your single switch that you hadn't intended. Condensation perhaps, a rat or spider making a nest, or a dropped spanner from a careless mechanic. Then, having both terminals disconnected might improve things.

Comment: Messy reality is exactly what I was wondering about

Comment: Only you know how messy your reality is going to get. Is there access for rats or spiders to get in? Will it be operated with condensing moisture?